# Populating a dictionary from a nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a list that nest list with pairs:

`my_list = [[5,8],[5,10],[3,1],[10,18],[10,20],[21,30]`

Now I want a dictionary that takes the first number as a key and then list all matching second numbers as value: so {3: [1], 5: [8,10], 10: [18,20], 21: [30]}

I already got a dictionary that consists of the necessary unique and sorted keys with empty values. How do populate this dictionary now with the correct values from the list?

Answer (score 2):

```
def foo(d, arr):
    for k, v in arr:
        if d.get(k):
            d[k].append(v)
        else:
            d[k] = [v]
            
d = {}
foo(d, my_list)
d
# {5: [8, 10], 3: [1], 10: [18, 20], 21: [30]}
```

Comment: `d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)` might be a better solution.

Comment: Better, yes @HampusLarsson but I think OP needs to focus on learning the fundamentals first.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) we can dynamically create the internal structure inside of the new dictionary without having to care to check if the `key` inside of the dictionary exists already or not:

```
my_list = [[5, 8], [5, 10], [3, 1], [10, 18], [10, 20], [21, 30]]

d = {}
for key, value in my_list:
    d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

print(d) # Output: {5: [8, 10], 3: [1], 10: [18, 20], 21: [30]}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does what I wanted it to do and it looks so simple.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
output = {}
def mapper(elem):
    values = output.get(elem[0], [])
    values.append(elem[1])
    output[elem[0]] = values
    return output

map(mapper, my_list)
```

---

As mentioned by @DeepSpace, this solution is not valid in Python 3.

Comment: This only works (as posted) on Python 2, which should definitely not be used in October '21. In Python 3, printing `output` after the call to `map` will show it's an empty dict

Comment: Can you explain more ? map() is already used in Python 3.10 https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: I did not write that Python 3 does not have `map`, just that this code does not work as expected since `map` returns a lazy object that has to be iterated over in order for the passed function to actually be called. Anyway, this is *not* a good use case for `map`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation